# HTML Button and href prbolem

Tags: javascript, html, button, href

I have created this simple HTML code but every time I click the button 'push it' it takes me to the link of the above movie. I am not understanding what is happening and it is getting on my nerves. If I change the location of the button, clicking it will go to the link of the above movie. For example if I put this button below Platoon movie clicking it will take me to the Platoon movie page whereas I dont want this button to do anything.
PLZ HELP ME
THANKS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> 
    <title>Movies List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>List of Movies</h1>
      <ol>
     <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune"></>Jodorowsky's Dune</li>
     <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platoon_(film)"></>Platoon</li>
     <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raging_Bull"></>Raging Bull</li>
     <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_(2005_film)"></>Stay</li>
     <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Equalizer_(film)"></>The Equlizer</li>
      </ol>
      <button>push it</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @bukko *Why put the HREF in then?* - without the href how will the user navigate to that page? the href isn't the problem, not closing the anchor tags is the issue.

Comment: ...which is why when I re-read the question I deleted my comment.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ is your friend.

Comment: @bukko Attention to detail is important.

Comment: Do you have a point?

Comment: @bukko Clearly made it, would you like to re-read the comments? Maybe you'll get it the second time round. =D Happy coding!

Comment: So, no then. Just being argumentative... Well done you!

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you don't closed the  tag.
remove the `</>` before the movie name, and add `</a>` after the movie name, doing this, the  tag will be only affecting the movie name, if you don't close the  tag it will be linking everything after it starts (in your case the button).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed your anchor tags. Anchor tags are closed using `</a>` not `</>`.

> Example: `<a href="http://example.com/">Anchor Text`**`</a>`**

```
  <ol>
    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune">Jodorowsky's Dune</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platoon_(film)">Platoon</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raging_Bull">Raging Bull</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_(2005_film)">Stay</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Equalizer_(film)">The Equlizer</a></li> 
  </ol>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You should close the anchor tag.

Like this one :

```
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune">Jodorowsky's Dune</a></li>
```

Please see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o5sbc1gf/)

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close your "a" tag

```
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune"></>Jodorowsky's Dune</li>
```

Change to:

```
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jodorowsky%27s_Dune">Jodorowsky's Dune</a></li>
```